# Optimal Crucible to Magmatic Dynamos ratio

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

Playing on Agrarian Skies 2, What is the ratio of Crucibles to Magmatic Dynamos to obtain maximum power generation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you use to heat up the crucible the complete list is here

http://ex-nihilo-minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Crucible

if you use lava, it will produce 4 mb/sec of lava per crucible which is 0.2mb/t, and if the dynamo produces 180,000rf per 1000mb of lava and is producing this at 120rf/t then it will take 1500 ticks for it to use a bucket of lava so which is 0.6mb/t meaning you need some ratio of **1 dynamos with 3 crucibles**

but if you use fire it produces 6 mb/sec which is 0.3mb/t which would be **1 dynamos to 2 crucibles**

sorry my math was wrong first time, I know it seemed off just did 1 division wrong should have double checked but hey it's fixed now

Comment: This is clearly not right. First of all, the energy tab on the Magmatic Dynamo states 120RF/t. Secondly that math is wrong. 2250 ticks per bucket does not equals 2.25 mB/t but  0.(4) mB/t. Finally, I am able to maintain 4 Magmatic Dynamos with 9 Crucible with lava to spare.

Comment: @DarkDestry fixed the math, you got augments in normally it prodces 80rf/t or is that changes with AS2?

Comment: I didnt use any augments so I assume its default. Ill check the cfgs.

Comment: The base power for magmatic is set to 120 in the cfig so I assume its the modpack author's configurations.

Comment: Yeah AS2 changes lots like the original one did, my bad for not checking in the first place